# How to sleep one thread while other threads is working in visualC#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to make two threads like `thread1` and `thread2`

and individually control them but when I do `thread1.Sleep(1000)`, it gives an error.

> Member 'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int)' cannot be accessed with an
>   instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

How can I do this?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is a static method. You can't use it with an instance.

Comment: @SonerGönül any other solution for this.?

Comment: Thread calling static method `Thread.Sleep` will sleep for specified milliseconds.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I want to know how can I do `thread1.Sleep(1000)` or any alternate way

Comment: @user007 Look at answer given by Kayani.

Comment: Are you trying to get a thread to suspend itself or are you trying to "reach in" from the outside and put a thread to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the Thread.Sleep(1000) in the function that is being executed by thread1.

For example you have :

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(MyFunction);
thread1.Start();
```

than in MyFunction call the Thread.Sleep(1000);